# About Corolla Theme Logo

Tags: 7, media

I am using my logo with the [Corolla theme](http://drupal.org/project/corolla) but its give me the following error:

> No setting detected for Mobile first or Desktop first. Please review "Settings > Mobile first or Desktop first" and select an option.

What do I have to do? How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 3):

You're using the 3.x-dev version of Corolla, which is not quite ready for release.  You should consider using the stable 2.x release instead.

To fix the error, you will need to go the Corolla theme administration page (/admin/appearance/settings/corolla) and choose either "mobile first" or "desktop first" under "CSS Global Settings."

P.S.  In the future, this type of theme-specific question should be filed as a "Support request" in the [Corolla issue queue](http://drupal.org/project/issues/corolla?categories=All).